# React Native + React Native Keychain + Jest: How to correctly mock React Native Keychain?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, mocking, jestjs

I'm trying to write unit tests for my helper functions for React-Native-Keychain.

Here are these helper functions:

```
import {
  setGenericPassword,
  getGenericPassword,
  resetGenericPassword
} from "react-native-keychain";

export const setToken = token => setGenericPassword("session", token);
export const getToken = () => getGenericPassword().then(creds => creds.password);
export const clearToken = () => resetGenericPassword();
```

And here are my tests:

```
import * as keyChainFunctions from "react-native-keychain";
import { setToken, getToken, clearToken } from "./secureStorage";

const token = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

jest.mock("react-native-keychain", () => {
  const token = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  const credentials = {
    username: "session",
    token: token
  };
  return {
    setGenericPassword: jest.fn(
      (username, password) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(true)) // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
    ),
    getGenericPassword: jest.fn(() => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(credentials))), // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
    resetGenericPassword: jest.fn(() => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(true))) // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  };
});

describe("set token", () => {
  it("saves the token in the keychain", () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    return setToken(token).then(() => {
      expect(keyChainFunctions.setGenericPassword).toHaveBeenCalledWith("session", token);
    });
  });
});

describe("get token", () => {
  it("retrieves the token from keychain", () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    return getToken().then(() => {
      expect(keyChainFunctions.getGenericPassword).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});

describe("clear token", () => {
  it("removes the token from the keychain", () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    return clearToken().then(() => {
      expect(keyChainFunctions.resetGenericPassword).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

As you can see I tried to mock the functions from React-Native-Keychain. But these tests fail, as they say no assertions happened. But I have to write these assertions since the helper functions are (/should be) asynchrous.

How am I supposed to mock the keyChainFunctions? Or is there a better way to test these helper functions?

### Edit

Just as Xarvalus requested, here are the errors:

```
npm test -t secureStorage

> ordersome@0.0.1 test /Users/jan/Startup/react-native/ordersome
> jest "secureStorage"

 FAIL  app/api/secureStorage/secureStorage.test.js
  set token
    ✕ saves the token in the keychain (60ms)
  get token
    ✕ retrieves the token from keychain (1ms)
  clear token
    ✕ removes the token from the keychain (1ms)

  ● set token › saves the token in the keychain


    expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalledWith()

    jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
    Received: undefined

      23 |     expect.assertions(1);
      24 |     return setToken(token).then(() => {
    > 25 |       expect(keyChainFunctions.setGenericPassword).toHaveBeenCalledWith("session", token);
         |                                                    ^
      26 |     });
      27 |   });
      28 | });

      at app/api/secureStorage/secureStorage.test.js:25:52
      at tryCallOne (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
      at node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
      at flush (node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)

  ● set token › saves the token in the keychain

    expect.assertions(1)
Expected one assertion to be called but received zero assertion calls.

      21 | describe("set token", () => {
      22 |   it("saves the token in the keychain", () => {
    > 23 |     expect.assertions(1);
         |            ^
      24 |     return setToken(token).then(() => {
      25 |       expect(keyChainFunctions.setGenericPassword).toHaveBeenCalledWith("session", token);
      26 |     });

      at Object.<anonymous> (app/api/secureStorage/secureStorage.test.js:23:12)

  ● get token › retrieves the token from keychain


    expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalled()

    jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
    Received: undefined

      32 |     expect.assertions(1);
      33 |     return getToken().then(() => {
    > 34 |       expect(keyChainFunctions.getGenericPassword).toHaveBeenCalled();
         |                                                    ^
      35 |     });
      36 |   });
      37 | });

      at app/api/secureStorage/secureStorage.test.js:34:52
      at tryCallOne (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
      at node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
      at flush (node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
● get token › retrieves the token from keychain

    expect.assertions(1)

    Expected one assertion to be called but received zero assertion calls.

      30 | describe("get token", () => {
      31 |   it("retrieves the token from keychain", () => {
    > 32 |     expect.assertions(1);
         |            ^
      33 |     return getToken().then(() => {
      34 |       expect(keyChainFunctions.getGenericPassword).toHaveBeenCalled();
      35 |     });

      at Object.<anonymous> (app/api/secureStorage/secureStorage.test.js:32:12)


  ● clear token › removes the token from the keychain

    expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalled()

    jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
    Received: undefined

      41 |     expect.assertions(1);
      42 |     return clearToken().then(() => {
    > 43 |       expect(keyChainFunctions.resetGenericPassword).toHaveBeenCalled();
         |                                                      ^
      44 |     });
      45 |   });
      46 | });

      at app/api/secureStorage/secureStorage.test.js:43:54
      at tryCallOne (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
      at node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
      at flush (node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
● clear token › removes the token from the keychain

    expect.assertions(1)

    Expected one assertion to be called but received zero assertion calls.

      39 | describe("clear token", () => {
      40 |   it("removes the token from the keychain", () => {
    > 41 |     expect.assertions(1);
         |            ^
      42 |     return clearToken().then(() => {
      43 |       expect(keyChainFunctions.resetGenericPassword).toHaveBeenCalled();
      44 |     });

      at Object.<anonymous> (app/api/secureStorage/secureStorage.test.js:41:12)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       3 failed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.961s
Ran all test suites matching /secureStorage/i.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Comment: Can you clarify the "But these tests fail, as they say no assertions happened" problem? I cannot reproduce the case as your tests simply pass in my fresh React-Native project.

Comment: @Xarvalus Thank you for your help! I added the errors that I get :)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce your errors, maybe the version reference would be useful for your case: `react 16.4.1, react-native 0.56.0, react-native-keychain 3.0.0-rc.3`; and in dev: `@babel/core ^7.0.0-beta.47, babel-core ^7.0.0-beta.47, babel-jest 23.4.0, babel-preset-react-native ^5, jest 23.4.0, react-test-renderer 16.4.1` within my project your tests works like a charm :)

Comment: @Xarvalus That's super weird. I have no idea why my wouldn't work. Here is my babel related information: `"@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.52","babel-core": "^7.0.0-beta.47","babel-eslint": "^8.2.5","babel-jest": "23.2.0","babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.2"`. Thank you for helping me !

Comment: Tried your config but encountered only problem like here [Jest issue #19859](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19859). Version bump of Jest to `23.4.0` resolves it.